# If $b(x)/a(x)$ converges the division to $0$, then would function it always be that $a(x)>b(x)$ at some point?

Tags: calculus, limits

I wonder if having two always differentiable function $a(x)$ and $b(x)$, with $\lim \limits _{x\to \infty}\dfrac{b(x)}{a(x)}=0$, would seem to imply that $a(x)$ is always strictly greater than $b(x)$ from some point on?  Logically I think that sounds correct, but not sure what theorem or statement could prove it.

Comment: No, for example $\frac{1}{-x} \to 0$ for $x \to \infty$.

Comment: @psl2Z hm what about when the function b(x) is not a constant?

Comment: Take $\frac{x}{-x^2} \to 0$

Comment: If you modify it to $|a(x)| > |b(x)|$ for some $x$, then this is correct. Indeed, it's not just true for some $x$, it's true for all sufficiently large $x$. This can be seen from using the $\varepsilon$-$N$ definition of $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{b(x)}{a(x)} = 0$, using $\varepsilon = 1$.

Comment: @TheoBendit ah I see. so what about if a(x) > |b(x)|, would that imply that  $lim_{→∞} ()/()=0$ ?

Comment: @strugglingeconomist123 Not necessarily, e.g. if $a(x) = 2|x|$ and $b(x) = |x|$. Note: this condition of $|a(x)| > |b(x)|$ is equivalent to the limit definition of $\lim_{x \to \infty} b(x)/a(x) = 0$ holding for $\varepsilon = 1$. So, my example holds for $\varepsilon = 1$, but not $\varepsilon = 1/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR: This is true iff $a(x)$ is eventually positive, and the *opposite* is true iff $a(x)$ is eventually negative. And $a(x)$ must either be eventually positive or eventually negative.**

If $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{b(x)}{a(x)} = 0$, then this implies that there is an $x_0$ such that $|a(x)|$ is positive for all $x>x_0$ [otherwise $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{b(x)}{a(x)}$ would not even exist]. Thus this implies that there is an an $x_0$ such that both

- The value $a(x_0)$ is either positive or negative [not $0$] and $a(x)$ stays the same sign as $a(x_0)$ for all $x>x_0$ i.e., $a(x)$ is either positive for all $x>x_0$, or $a(x)$ is negative for all $x>x_0$.
- The inequality $|\frac{b(x)}{a(x)}| < 1$ holds for all $x>x_0$.

**If $a(x)$ is positive** for all $x> x_0$, then for the inequality $|\frac{b(x)}{a(x)}| < 1$ to hold, the inequality $|b(x)| < |a(x)|$ must hold. But then $a(x)$ positive implies th equation $a(x)=|a(x)|$, so the inequality $|b(x)|<|a(x)|= a(x)$, or $|b(x)|<a(x)$ must hold. But then $b(x) \le |b(x)|$ so if the inequality $|b(x)|<a(x)$ holds, then so must the inequality $b(x)<a(x)$ hold. **So if $a(x)$ is positive for all $x> x_0$, then  the inequality $b(x) < a(x)$ must hold for all $x> x_0$.**

**If $a(x)$ is negative** for all $x> x_0$, then it is a different story. The inequality $|\frac{b(x)}{a(x)}| < 1$ will hold whenever $|b(x)| < |a(x)|$. But here $a(x)=-|a(x)|$ [because $a(x)$ is negative], and $-b(x) \le |b(x)|$. So $|b(x)| < |a(x)|$ implies $-b(x) \le |b(x)| < |a(x)| =-a(x)$, or in particular $-b(x) < -a(x)$. Multiplying both sides of this by $-1$ gives here $b(x) > a(x)$. **So if $a(x)$ is negative for all $x> x_0$, then  the opposite inequality $b(x) < a(x)$ must hold for all $x> x_0$.**

For example, take $a(x) = -x^2-1$ and $b(x) = x+3$. Then note that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{b(x)}{a(x)} = 0$, but because $a(x)$ is negative, the inequality $b(x)>a(x)$ holds everywhere on the real line [even if $|b(x)|<|a(x)|$ for all large $x$].